# How to get the value of a previously entered argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this slash command:

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="buy", description="Buy an item from the shop")
@app_commands.autocomplete(item=item_autocomplete)
async def buy(interaction: discord.Interaction, item:str, amount:int):
```

And what I want to do is get the value of `item` to determine the autocomplete of `amount`.
because some items have different max quantities that I only want the user to pick from. If you need more of an idea here's the autocomplete function:

```py
shop_items = [
  {
    "name": "test",
    "price": 1,
    "max_quantity": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "price": 2,
    "max_quantity": 10
  }
]

async def item_autocomplete(interaction: discord.Interaction, current: str):
    return [
        app_commands.Choice(name=item["name"], value=item["name"])
        for item in shop_items if current.lower() in item["name"].lower()
    ]
```

Comment: You could put it into a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar This bot will be used by multiple users, so I don't think that would work.

Comment: Use a dictionary keyed by username?

Comment: @Barmar I wouldn't be able to get the value of `item` until the command is run though.

Comment: Of course not, since the first function sets `item` to be used by the second one.

Comment: Is `buy_autocomplete()` called by `buy()`? If it is, then you should pass `item` as an argument.

Comment: @Barmar No, it is a decorator. And I am not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `item_autocomplete()`.

Comment: I didn't see that it was referenced in the decorator argument.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`Command.autocomplete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=autocomplete#discord.app_commands.Command.autocomplete) quite literally have the answer...

> The coroutine callback must have 2 parameters, **the Interaction**, and the current value by the user (the string currently being typed by the user).
>
> **To get the values from other parameters that may be filled in, accessing Interaction.namespace will give a Namespace object with those values.**

Referred to from [`app_commands.autocomplete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=autocomplete#discord.app_commands.autocomplete) (the one you're using):

> For more information, see the Command.autocomplete() documentation.

Keep in mind that users can fill in their arguments in any order, so `item` may be empty when the users are typing in a value for `amount`. Also, autocompletes are only a *suggestion*, they can send you whatever value they want to, so make sure to manually check the value in your `buy` command afterwards.